# Banner Grabbing DNS?

Tags: netcat, banner, hacking

How does one banner grab DNS? I'm able to banner grab other services such as HTTP/FTP/SMTP but for DNS it's not immediately obvious.

Typically for HTTP I use `nc` with `HEAD / HTTP/1.1 {ENTER}{ENTER}`.

I had assumed that it'd be possible with DNS if you know the initial structure of the query, but I can't seem to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS does not have a "banner" to grab.  The closest equivalent is a magic query for `version.bind.    CHAOS    TXT` which will work on most BIND nameservers.
You can perform this query using `dig`:

> `dig version.bind CHAOS TXT`

If that does not work you can use fingerprinting techniques to determine the remote server's version -- the [`fpdns`](https://github.com/kirei/fpdns) tool is one option for that, but there are others.